Xcode keeps giving me problems with this code
Xcode keeps saying

Invalid redeclaration of ContentView.
Instance will be immediately deallocated because property navigationDelegate is weak.
weak may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not FilesView.
Value of type WebViewCoordinator has no member getDocumentsDirectory.
Value of type WebViewCoordinator has no member sanitizeFileName.
Value of type [URLResourceKey: Any] has no member totalFileAllocatedSize

here's the code:
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@main
struct UDOWNLOADERZApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            BrowserView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Browser", systemImage: "globe")
                }
            FilesView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Files", systemImage: "folder")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct BrowserView: View {
    @State private var webView = WKWebView()

    var body: some View {
        WebView(webView: $webView)
            .onAppear {
                let urls = ["https://youtube.com", "https://soundcloud.com"]
                for url in urls {
                    if let url = URL(string: url) {
                        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                        webView.load(request)
                    }
                }
                webView.navigationDelegate = WebViewCoordinator(filesView: nil)
            }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var webView: WKWebView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {}
}

class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    weak var filesView: FilesView?

    init(filesView: FilesView?) {
        self.filesView = filesView
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let jsCode = """
        (function() {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
            var mediaElement = video || audio;
            if (mediaElement) {
                return {
                    src: mediaElement.src,
                    title: document.title || mediaElement.getAttribute('title') || 'Unknown'
                };
            }
            return null;
        })();
        """
        
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsCode) { [weak self] (result, error) in
            guard let resultDict = result as? [String: String], let urlString = resultDict["src"], let title = resultDict["title"], let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
            
            self?.downloadContent(url: url, title: title)
        }
    }

    func downloadContent(url: URL, title: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let destinationURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(sanitizeFileName(fileName: title)).mp4")

            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { [weak self] (tempURL, response, error) in
                guard let self = self, let tempURL = tempURL, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempURL, to: destinationURL)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("DownloadCompleted"), object: nil)
                        self.filesView?.reloadFilesList()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Download failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}

struct FilesView: View {
    @State private var downloadedFiles = [String]()
    @State private var storageTaken: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(downloadedFiles, id: \.self) { file in
                    Text(file)
                }
            }
            Text("Storage Taken: \(storageTaken)")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadFiles)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("DownloadCompleted"))) { _ in
            loadFiles()
        }
    }

    func loadFiles() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do {
                let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: getDocumentsDirectory(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    downloadedFiles = files.map { $0.lastPathComponent }
                    calculateStorageTaken(files: files)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load files: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    func reloadFilesList() {
        loadFiles()
    }

    private func calculateStorageTaken(files: [URL]) {
        let size = files.reduce(0, { $0 + ($1 as NSURL).fileSize() })
        storageTaken = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(size), countStyle: .file)
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Contact: Udownloaderz2@proton.me")
            Text("Twitter: N/A")
        }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

func sanitizeFileName(fileName: String) -> String {
    let invalidCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\\/:*?\"<>|")
    return fileName.components(separatedBy: invalidCharacters).joined(separator: "_")
}

extension NSURL {
    func fileSize() -> Int {
        guard`


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


Invalid redeclaration of 'ContentView’. Somewhere in the project, there's an another declaration of ContentView. In Swift, it's not allowed to have more than one class, struct, or protocol with the same name. You should find it and delete or rename.
Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'navigationDelegate' is 'weak’. If you write weak var, it indicates that you want to maintain a weak reference to an object. However, the object must have at least one strong reference, or it will be deallocated immediately. In your case, you must retain WebViewCoordinator somewhere with a strong reference, like var webViewCoordinator: WebViewCoordinator, and then assign it to the delegate property.
'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'FilesView’. In Swift, only reference types can have weak references. Since structures in Swift are value types, you can't use weak references with them. In your scenario, there are several conceptual misunderstandings. There's no need to pass a view to another class if you want to reload it.
I can't provide feedback on the errors related to getDocumentsDirectory, sanitizeFileName, and totalFileAllocatedSize because in your example, you've moved them to a location where they no longer produce errors.

To summarize, consider restructuring your architecture by introducing ViewModels and Services. For instance, you could create a service to handle methods like getDocumentsDirectory and sanitizeFileName, utilizing this service where necessary.
Additionally, create a ViewModel and pass it to 'WebViewCoordinator' and 'FilesView'. The coordinator can then request file reloading, and 'FilesView' can retrieve reloaded files from the ViewModel.
